# Refresh Token for umi request interceptors response

Tags: javascript, axios, antd, ant-design-pro, umijs

I use tokens as authorization, when the token expires, I want to create a new token using the refresh token. I can do this with the axios library but I couldn't find how to do it with umi request. Anyone translate the code sample given below to an umi request interceptor example?

this axios interceptors response for my refresh token operation.

```
  let isRefreshing: boolean = false;
  let failedQueue: any = [];

  const processQueue = (error: any, token: any = null) => {
    failedQueue.forEach((prom: any) => {
      if (error) {
        prom.reject(error);
      } else {
        prom.resolve(token);
      }
    });

    failedQueue = [];
  };

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    async response => {
      return response;
    },
    async error => {
      debugger;
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      if (error.response) {
        const status = error.response.status;
        const refreshToken = getStoredUserAuth().refreshToken;
        if (status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
          if (isRefreshing) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
            })
              .then(token => {
                originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
                return axios(originalRequest);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                return Promise.reject(err);
              });
          }

          originalRequest._retry = true;
          isRefreshing = true;

          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            refreshAccessToken(refreshToken)
              .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                  if (response.data.token) {
                    setAuthStatus(response.data);
                    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
                      "Bearer " + response.data.token;
                    originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] =
                      "Bearer " + response.data.token;
                  }
                  processQueue(null, response.data.token);
                  resolve(axios(originalRequest));
                } else {
                  throw new Error();
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                //console.log(err);
                failedQueue = [];
                setUnauthStatus();
                source.cancel("Session time out");
                processQueue(err, null);
                reject(err);
              })
              .then(() => {
                isRefreshing = false;
              });
          });
        }
      } else {
        debugger;
        errorHandler(error);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

I use to ant design pro V5 version, so I've tried to refresh token with umi request but I could'nt do it, As in the axios library, I cannot write for umi request, I cannot establish its logic. So can anyone write the same example (axios.interceptors.response) above for umi request?

```
const requestInterceptors = (url: string, options: RequestOptionsInit) => {
  if (tokenService.check()) {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenService.parse()?.token}`,
    };
    return {
      url,
      options: { ...options, headers },
    };
  }
  return {
    url,
    options: { ...options },
  };
};

const responseInterceptors = (response: Response, options: RequestOptionsInit) => {

// I could'nt this part for refresh token like axios interceptors. I need help for that

return response;
}

export const request: RequestConfig = {
  errorHandler,
  requestInterceptors: [requestInterceptors],
  responseInterceptors: [responseInterceptors]
};
```

[umi request github link for documentation](https://github.com/umijs/umi-request)

Comment: Anyone could help me to write that function ?

Comment: I still could not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution for handling refresh token in umi-request/ant-design-pro, no need for `queue`s, works like a charm

```js
// Neccesary imports
import type { RequestConfig } from 'umi';
import { request as requestUmi } from 'umi';
import type {
  RequestInterceptor,
  RequestOptionsInit,
  ResponseError,
} from 'umi-request';
import Reqs from 'umi-request';
import merge from 'lodash/merge';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

// My personal type definitions
namespace API {
  export interface LoginResult {
    access: string;
    refresh: string;
  }
}

// Part 1: "Simple" Error Handler =))
const errorHandler = (error: ResponseError) => {
  console.log('HTTP ERROR', error);
  throw error;
};

// Part 2: Request Interceptors, (use this instead of "headers" directly in request config)
const requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor = (url, options) => {
  return {
    url,
    options: merge(cloneDeep(options), {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt.getAccess()}` },
    }),
  };
};

// Part 3: Response Interceptos
const { cancel } = Reqs.CancelToken.source();
let refreshTokenRequest: Promise<API.LoginResult> | null = null;
const responseInterceptor = async (
  response: Response,
  options: RequestOptionsInit
) => {
  const accessTokenExpired = response.status === 401;
  if (accessTokenExpired) {
    try {
      if (!refreshTokenRequest) {
        refreshTokenRequest = refreshAccessToken(jwt.getRefresh());
      }
      // multiple requests but "await"ing for only 1 refreshTokenRequest, because of closure
      const res = await refreshTokenRequest;
      if (!res) throw new Error();
      if (res.access) jwt.saveAccess(res.access);
      if (res.refresh) jwt.saveRefresh(res.refresh); // for ROTATE REFRESH TOKENS
      return requestUmi(
        response.url,
        merge(cloneDeep(options), {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res.access}` },
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      jwt.removeAccess();
      jwt.removeRefresh();
      cancel('Session time out.');
      throw err;
    } finally {
      refreshTokenRequest = null;
    }
  }

  return response;
};

export const request: RequestConfig = {
  errorHandler,
  // This would fuck the refresh token logic, use requestInterceptors instead,
  // because jwt.getAccess() will not being called everytime, but only the first time => lead to stale access token
  // headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt.getAccess()}` },

  // Handle refresh token (old): https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/7159#issuecomment-680789397
  // Handle refresh token (new): https://gist.github.com/paulnguyen-mn/8a5996df9b082c69f41bc9c5a8653533
  requestInterceptors: [requestInterceptor],
  responseInterceptors: [responseInterceptor],
};
```

Also posted [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/7159#issuecomment-813450218)